# Autoboxing and overloading

Tags: java, overloading, autoboxing

```
public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaA a = new JavaB();
        a.m1(5);
        a.m1(new Integer(5));
    }

}

class JavaA{

    public void m1(Integer i){
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}

class JavaB extends JavaA{

    public void m1(int i){
        System.out.println(1);
    }

}
```

Output: 2   2

As per my understanding, output would be "1  2".

1) When I am calling method a.m1(5) from main method. As per overloading concept, class JavaB's method should get executed. but it wont.

Please help me to understand the concept of overloading+autoboxing.

Comment: Output is 2,2, i checked it

Comment: "As per my understanding, output would be "1 2"." Why? What leads you to that conclusion? Hint: you should differentiate between *overloading* and *overriding*. I suspect that's the problem here.

Answer (score 5):

```
JavaA a = new JavaB();
a.m1(5);
a.m1(new Integer(5));
```

- the static type of `a` is `JavaA`
- `JavaA` declares just one method `m1`
- that method accepts an `Integer`
- it is applicable to both calls

The method signature is resolved at *compile* time. The compiler considers only the signatures declared in the static type of the target expression (`JavaA` in your case).

Comment: Good answer, the type of `a` isn't really static though.  I'd suggest a little wording change.

Comment: What do you mean? Java is a statically typed language and the (static) type of the variable `a` is `JavaA`.

Comment: Just that `a` is variable, and can be reassigned, so the variable's type isn't static.  In the question the type of `a` is `JavaB` at runtime.  It could be assigned to an instance of `JavaA`, and the type of variable A would then change.

Comment: You are confusing the (static) type of the variable with the (dynamic) type of its value.

Answer (score 1):

The decision on which overloaded method will be chosen is done at compile time, based on the methods available for the compile time type. Your `a` variable has a compile type of `JavaA`, and `JavaA` only has a single `m1` method, so that's the only method that can be chosen.

`m1` of `JavaB` class can't be a candidate, even though the run-time type of `a` is `JavaB`.

Therefore you get the output

```
2
2
```

Comment: You are right, in order to have an output of `1, 2`, `JavaB a = new JavaB();`  is needed

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling `JavaB.m1` twice, since your object is only ever an instance of `JavaB`.  Here's an example which will do what you're wanting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaA a = new JavaA();
    JavaA b = new JavaB();
    a.m1(5);
    b.m1(new Integer(5));
    //output will be 
    //2
    //1
}
```

Both objects can act as an object of type JavaA due to polymorphism, but the instance can be of any subclass of `JavaA`.  The overriden implementation of m1 will be called when the actual type is of `JavaB`.  The original implementation will be called when the instance type is `JavaA`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `int` and `Integer` aren't the same types when it comes to overriding methods. This means that method `m1` from `JavaB` doesn't override `m1` from `JavaA`. You can check it with the use of `@Override` annotation - it simply doesn't work here. In compile time these two methods are overloaded, not overriden, so when in your `main()` method you want to treat `a` as it is of type `JavaA` here: `JavaA a = new JavaB();` then there is no other choice than calling method from `JavaA` - polymorphism have no use here.